# Azure Devops Pull Request Validation with a Pipeline Trigger

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, pull-request, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to set up pull request validation for a repository, and I want to base it on a YAML build pipeline I already have configured. The problem is that this pipeline is triggered by another pipeline, because it relies on an artifact published by the other pipeline.

The parent pipeline just builds the project and outputs the result.

The second pipeline then scans the build artifact for security vulnerabilities with NPM audit.

I want them as separate PR pipelines because I don't want to fail the build just because of security issues, but I do want it to show on the PR.

The first (build) pipeline is also a build policy for the PR, so it will definitely run every time I want the second pipeline to also run.

Is there any way to do this with a YAML pipeline, or is it only possible with a release pipeline?

I've tried adding the audit pipeline as a build policy on the master branch, but this just triggers the pipeline instantly the moment a PR is created, and since there's no triggering branch it uses the latest - which is not what I want.

I also tried to manually post a status from the pipeline for the PR to check, but I can't figure out how to do it.

Comment: Why not make them the same pipeline, then control which steps run under different circumstances with conditions?

Comment: @DanielMann I want them split into separate pipelines because 1) I want multiple checks in the PR so reviewers don't have to drill down into the build unless there's an issue and 2) I want the build to succeed and produce a build artifact that could be released/tested even if the scan pipeline returns issues. They are currently the same pipeline - I'm trying to change that.